# Bootstrap responsive issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The idea is if I use the `container` class it works form zoom in and zoom out, but it does not on responsive. If I use `container-fluid` class it works for responsive, but it does not work on zoom in or out. How do I make this work to be responsive and for the zoom in or out? This is a part from HTML code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class ="row">
              <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
              <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="row svu-info1">
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 svu-info1-text1">
                            <p class="text-header">&Icirc;nve&#539;i, te consul&#539;i, faci schimb de cuno&#x219;tin&#539;e, te specialiezi! </p>

                            <p class="text-body"><span class="p-header"></span> este un program intern care 
                            ofer&#259; posibilitatea tuturor colegilor s&#259; se dezvolte 
                            profesional. Este un centru de cuno&#x219;tin&#539;e &#x219;i expertiz&#259;, 
                            este locul unde ne ajut&#259;m reciproc &#x219;i unde &#238;ntreb&#259;rile
                            noastre &#238;&#x219;i g&#259;sesc r&#259;spunsul.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 bg-img1">
                            <!-- <img src ="<?php echo Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(); ?>/images/pages/svu/img_svu_1.jpg" alt="img_svu_1"> -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-3"></div>

        </div> 
        <div class ="row  bg-white">
              <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
              <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="row svu-info2">
                          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 svu-info2-text2">
                             <p class="">TEST University include 10 comunit&#259;&#539;i tehnice,</p>
                             <p class="">fiecare dintre ele av&#226;nd un decan - coordonator &#x219;i un nucleu tehnic</p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
                             <div class="row elements1">
                                 <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 first">.NET</div>
                                 <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 second">
                                    <!-- <img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(); ?>/images/pages/svu/img_svu_android.png" alt="" /> -->
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 third">ANDROID</div>
                             </div>
                          </div>
                    </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
        </div>

        <div class ="row  bg-white">
              <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
              <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="row">
                         <div class ="col-xs-2 bg-img2">
                            <!-- <img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(); ?>/images/pages/svu/img_svu_ios.png" alt="" /> -->
                        </div>
                        <div class ="col-xs-10  elements2">
                            <div class="row row1">
                                     <div class="col-sm-2 elem1">IOS</div>
                                     <div class="col-sm-2 elem2">
                                        <!-- <img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(); ?>/images/pages/svu/img_svu_pm.png" alt="" /> -->
                                     </div>
                                     <div class="col-sm-2 elem3">PM</div>
                                     <div class="col-sm-2 elem4">C/C++</div>
                                     <div class="col-sm-2 elem5">DataBase</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row row2">
                                     <div class="col-sm-2 elem1">DevOps</div>
                                     <div class="col-sm-2 elem2">Java</div>
                                     <div class="col-sm-2 elem3">QA</div>
                                     <div class="col-sm-2 elem4">
                                        <!-- <img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(); ?>/images/pages/svu/img_svu_qa.png" alt="" /> -->
                                     </div>
                                     <div class="col-sm-2 elem5">WEB</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give both `container` and `container-fluid` class in your div. e.g `<div class="container-fluid container">`. Maybe it'll do work for you.

Comment: Thx for the help, but if i use only container  or with container-fluid it totally messed up all my page :|

Comment: Ok. Then you should set your class's div according to window's size. get the window size using jQurey

<script type="text/javascript">


 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var bodywidth = jQuery('body').width();


/*alert(docheight+'--'+bodyheight);*/

if (bodywidth <= 1000) {

    $("div").removeClass( "container" ).addClass( "container-fluid" );

    }


});
</script>

Comment: Put the upper code in your head tag and try it again

Comment: Sorry there was some mistake it is working for me

if (bodywidth >= 1000)
{
 $("div").removeClass( "container-fluid" ).addClass( "container" ); } 
 });

Comment: its ok, but i believe that i can be solved using just css and html, i don't want to use jquery for this.

Comment: Okay as your wish but this is two line code reduce your code much more. All the best